# The getter 'todoText' isn't defined for the class 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following error in my code.

> The getter 'todoText' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
>
> Try importing the library that defines 'todoText', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'todoText'.dart(undefined_getter)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
    void main() => runApp(new ToDoApp());
    
    class ToDoApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          title: 'To Do Application',
          theme: new ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
           ),
          home: new ToDoList(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class ListItem{
      bool _todoCheck;
      ListItem(this._todoCheck);
    }
    class _strikeThrough extends StatelessWidget{
    
      final String todoText;
      final bool todoCheck;
      _strikeThrough(this.todoText, this.todoCheck) : super();
    
      Widget _widget(){
        if(todoCheck){
          return Text(
            todoText,
            style: TextStyle(
              decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontSize: 22.0,
              color: Colors.red[200],
            ),
          );
        }
        else{
          return Text(
            todoText,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22.0
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return _widget();
      }
    }
    class ToDoList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      createState() => new _TodoListState();
    }
    
    class _TodoListState extends State<ToDoList> {
      
      var textController = TextEditingController();
      var popUpTextController = TextEditingController();
    
      List<String> _todoItems = [];
      List<ListItem> WidgetList =[];
      void _addToDoItem(String task){
        if(task.length > 0){
          setState(()=> _todoItems.add(task));
        }
      }
    
      void _removeToDoItem(int index){
        setState(() => _todoItems.removeAt(index));
      }
    
      void _promptRemoveToDoItem(int index){
        showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Mark "${_todoItems[index]}" as Completed?'+' This will remove this Item'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()
                ),
             new FlatButton(
                child: new Text('MARK AS DONE'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _removeToDoItem(index);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: 'ToDo Task Deleted!'
                    );
                }
                ),
            ]
          );
        }
        );
      }
    
     Widget _buildToDoList(BuildContext context){
       return Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           new Flexible(
             child: new ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return _buildToDoItem(_todoItems[index], index); 
              },
              ), 
             ),
             new Expanded(
               child: ReorderableListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  for(final widget in _todoItems)
                  for(final widget1 in WidgetList)
                  GestureDetector(
                    key: Key(widget.todoText),
                    child: Dismissible(
                      key: Key(widget.todoText),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        value: widget1._todoCheck, 
                        title: _strikeThrough(widget.todoText,widget1._todoCheck),
                        onChanged: (checkValue){
                          setState(() {
                            if(!checkValue){
                              widget1._todoCheck = false;
                            }
                            else{
                              widget1._todoCheck = true;
                            }
                          });
                        }),
                        background: Container(
                          child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          color: Colors.orange[300],
                          ),
                          confirmDismiss: (dismissDirection){
                            return showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              barrierDismissible: true,
                              builder: (BuildContext context){
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text("Delete Todo?"),
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    FlatButton(
                                      child: Text("OK"),
                                       onPressed: (){
                                         Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                       },
                                      ),
                                      FlatButton(
                                        child: Text("Cancel"),
                                        onPressed: (){
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                        },),
                                  ],
                                  );
                              });
                          },
                          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                          movementDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                          onDismissed: (dismissedDirection){
                            WidgetList.remove(widget);
                            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: "Todo Deleted!"
                              );
                          },
                      ),
                    onDoubleTap: (){
                      popUpTextController.text = widget.todoText;
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        barrierDismissible: true,
                        builder: (BuildContext context){
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("Edit ToDo"),
                            content: TextFormField(
                              controller: popUpTextController,
                            ),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              FlatButton( 
                                child: Text("OK"),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    widget.todoText=popUpTextController.text;
                                  });
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                },
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                               child: Text("Cancel"),
                               onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                            },
                          )
                            ],
                          );
                        } 
                      );
                    },
                  )
                ],
                onReorder:  (oldIndex, newIndex){
              setState(() {
              if(oldIndex < newIndex){
                newIndex -= 1;
                }
              var replaceWiget = WidgetList.removeAt(oldIndex);
              WidgetList.insert(newIndex, replaceWiget);
              });
          },)
              )
           ],
        );    
     }
    
     Widget _buildToDoItem(String todoText, int index){
       return new ListTile(
         title: new Text(todoText),
         onLongPress: () => _promptRemoveToDoItem(index),
       );
     }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('To Do List')
              ),
              body:_buildToDoList(context),
              floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
              floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
                focusElevation: 7,
                onPressed:_pushAddToDoScreen,
                tooltip: 'Add Task',
                child: new Icon(Icons.add)
              ),
              
            drawer: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                children: <Widget>[
                    DrawerHeader(
                      child: Text('To Do App Drawer Header'),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                     )
                    ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Add Items'),
                    onTap: _pushAddToDoScreen,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Remove Items'),
                    subtitle: Text('Long Press on any item to remove it'),
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Check Status of Items'),
                    subtitle: Text('If the item is in List, then it is Pending, else long press to mark it done'),
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    )
                  ] 
                )
              )
          );
      }
    
    
     void _pushAddToDoScreen(){
      Navigator.of(context).push( 
        new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context){
            return new Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text('Add a new task')
              ),
              body: new TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                onSubmitted: (val){
                  _addToDoItem(val);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Tasks....',
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0)
                ),
              )
            );
          }
        )
      );
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Riya, try removing the call to super in your `_strikeThrough` class. (By the way, that's not Dart's class naming convention). I recommend you change that class' name to `_StrikeThrough`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction in _StrikeThrough but removing the call to super did not seem to help. Is there any other alternative?